# rand(000000, 999999) sometimes generate 4 digit numbers

Tags: php

I want to generate 6 digit numbers. 
Now this work great BUT occasionally it generates 4 digit numbers. Not often but some times it does. Why??

```
$num = rand(000000, 999999);
```

Comment: Four digit numbers are greater than zero

Comment: that needs to be 100000 not 000000

Comment: Wow, PHP accepts 000000 as a valid number? That seems pretty wrong. EDIT: I just tested Qalculate! (a calculator) and it accepts 0000 as well. Is this mathematically correct or just input sanitisation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$num = rand(100000, 999999);
```

Maybe this do the job :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate numbers from `000000` to `999999` with 6-digit padding, you can use the [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php) function.

```
$rand = rand(0, 999999);
echo str_pad($rand, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

`rand(000000, 999999)` is equal to `rand(0, 999999)`

It will return a number between 0 and 999999. In **90%** of all cases the number is **between 100000 and 999999** and you will have a **6 digit number**. That is why it works for you most of the time

But in **10%** of all cases, the number will be **smaller than 100000** and only contain **1 to 5 digits** (all numbers between 1 and 99999..not hard to figure out that 1 or 2 digits are still less propable then 4 or 5 digits)

To solve your problem you have to get a number from `rand(100000, 999999)`, but this won't contain any numbers starting with 0! The first digit will always be from 1 and 9.

The other answers already show nice solutions for getting 6 digits from 0 to 9. Another easy one would just be:

```
for($i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    $rand_digit[$i] = rand(0,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said, you could change `$num = rand(000000, 999999);` to `$num = rand(100000, 999999);`, but there might be a case where you need a number that has 6 digits, but whose value is below 100000. Ex. 001103. You can still use `$num = rand(000000, 999999);` but you would use something like:

```
$num = rand(000000, 999999);
$print_num = sprintf("%06d", $num);
```

This would not change the number, it will only give it a 6 digit format.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Note : 
Warning
min max range must be within the range getrandmax(). i.e. (max - min) <= getrandmax() Otherwise, rand() may return poor-quality random numbers.

So, an other note : 
Note: On some platforms (such as Windows), getrandmax() is only 32767. If you require a range larger than 32767, specifying min and max will allow you to create a range larger than this, or consider using **mt_rand()** instead.